# Slick2D Java game using method overloading for collision

Tags: java, overloading, collision, slick2d

All my game objects extend a class called `Entity`, and every instance is inserted into an `ArrayList<Entity>` when it is created.

My theory was that I would be able to loop through all objects on the screen, update them, and also check if they were colliding with any other objects from within a nested loop. If they were colliding, I could then pass the object they were colliding with into a method, onCollide, that would deal with the collision depending on what the object was; ie;

```
//Update Game Objects
if(gameObjects.size() > 0){
for(int counter = 0; counter < gameObjects.size(); counter ++){

    //Update every object.
    gameObjects.get(counter).update(gc, sbg, delta, gameObjects);

    //If the object is colliding with another object,
    for(int collisionCounter = 0; collisionCounter < gameObjects.size(); collisionCounter ++){

        if(gameObjects.get(counter).isColliding(gameObjects.get(collisionCounter))){    
            //Execute collision code for both objects.
            gameObjects.get(counter).onCollide(gameObjects.get(collisionCounter));
            gameObjects.get(collisionCounter).onCollide(gameObjects.get(counter));
        }
    }
}
}
```

However, due to the fact that my ArrayList consists of "Entity", Java does not allow me to overload methods like;

```
onCollide(Player player),
onCollide(Enemy enemy)
```

etc.

I want to avoid using `instanceof`, so is there a way to make use of polymorphism to achieve this effect, or a better way to do collision in general?

[Solved] Now using a String variable called "type" to determine differences between objects.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on why do you need an Entity to collide in a different manner depending on the collided object?

Comment: Not necessarily a different manner, simply carry out different actions - e.g, an enemy would remove health, while a power-up would cause the player to receive a temporary buff. onCollide would do something different depending on what an object collides with!

Comment: Instead of labeling your question as "solved", write what you did to solve it as an answer, then mark that answer as accepted.

Comment: Using a member variable for the type is basically the same as using `instanceof`. Why not just use the less error prone built-in if you're going with that?

Comment: @GoldenDragon There's no difference in terms of coupling between using "instanceof" and using a class token, or even `Class.getName`. I'd keep it simple: you are probably not interested in what happens when an enemy collides with another enemy, or when an enemy collides with a bonus item. You have your player and you check it against each other entity (O(N) loop instead of O(N^2)). Then just let each other entity collide with the player (collision logic implemented in each other entity).

Comment: @MisterSmith For some reason instanceof and Class.getName did not work! I am making a small shooter game, and have to do collision for most objects (I don't want enemies phasing through each other, after all!). Because I am proceedurally generating all objects, there is rarely going to be any more than a few dozen objects in the game at any one time, so I think looping through all objects will be OK! :S

Comment: @Makoto Thanks! I'll keep that in mind for next time! :D